# Regroup data from a table in a View

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using an example Will be easier to describe my issue.

Let's say that this is the table on which i make my postgresql query :

```
id | name | geolocation | parent_id 
-- | ---- | ----------- | ---------
 1 | aaaa |   0.0,0.0   |    
 2 | bbbb |   1.1,1.1   |     1
 3 | cccc |             |     1
 4 | dddd |   2.2,2.2   |   
 5 | eeee |             |
```

For the locations having no geolocation and a parent_id, i would like to create a view with 3 columns (id, name and geolocation) where these particular locations have the geolocation of their parent. With the example the created view would be :

```
id | name | geolocation 
-- | ---- | ----------- 
 1 | aaaa |   0.0,0.0   
 2 | bbbb |   1.1,1.1   
 3 | cccc |   0.0,0.0        
 4 | dddd |   2.2,2.2   
 5 | eeee |
```

Anyone can help ?

best regards and have a great day

Edit : empty geolocations are empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` with a subquery:

```
SELECT
 id,name,
 CASE 
   WHEN geolocation = '' THEN 
   (SELECT geolocation FROM t WHERE id = q1.parent_id)
 ELSE   
   geolocation
 END
FROM t q1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=41f3c738849cf0442361b9bd292f58b2)

Comment: hi Jim,
nothing else to say your query works perfectly so thanks for your answer, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Use a self `LEFT` join to link to the parent row and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,
       COALESCE(t1.geolocation, t2.geolocation) geolocation
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8db649f1250f9a2ecd72b693d54c3eb0).

If the empty geolocations are empty strings:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,
       CASE 
         WHEN t1.geolocation = '' THEN t2.geolocation 
         ELSE t1.geolocation
       END geolocation
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
```

Comment: hi @forpas,
i forgot to mention that geolocation are strings so no value means an empty string. your query works perfectly on another table where i need to do the same thing so thank you for your answer!

Comment: @ArmandViolle no value in sql means NULL irrespective of data type. I will edit for the case of empty string.

Comment: you're right I wasn't clear, i will edit my post too to avoid errors.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, do you have and idea of how i can make it recursive ? i tried with cte but i don't get the right result...